# How to pick random restaurant name from MapKit in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit

Im searching for a "food" place around my area and the return value is a bunch of restaurants with their name. How would I randomly pick only one of those and return the name in my `textLabel`? Right now it returns all the restaurant names in my `textLabel`.

```
        request.region = map.region
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = "food"
        
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        
        search.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in
           
           if error != nil {
              print("Error occured in search: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
           } else if response!.mapItems.count == 0 {
              print("No matches found")
           } else {
              print("Matches found")
              
              for item in response!.mapItems {
                 
                 print("Name = \(String(describing: item.name))")
                 print("Phone = \(String(describing: item.phoneNumber))")
                 
                 
              
                 
                 let resturantName = SKLabelNode()
                 resturantName.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 3.5)
                 resturantName.fontSize = 30
                 resturantName.fontName = "PingFangHK-Semibold"
                 resturantName.text = item.name
                 resturantName.fontColor = UIColor.white
                 resturantName.zPosition = 50
                 self.addChild(resturantName)
           }
        }
     })
```

Comment: You mean `response!.mapItems.randomElement()`?

Comment: I tried that but its still showing all the strings.

Comment: Well there is no `textLabel` in the code you showed, so it's hard to help. Your code cycles thru all the map items. I don't know what else you "tried".

Comment: resturantName is the `label`

Comment: `resturantName.text = item.name`

Comment: But in the code you've shown you are looping through all of them (`for item in response!.mapItems`).

Comment: Yes Im trying to get access to all the places in my area. I just want to be able to pick one and show it on the `label`.

Comment: Focus man, focus. You say you want to pick one of the array of restaurants returned. Matt told you how to do that. Update your question to show the code that you tried that is "still showing all the strings."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet should work:

```
    search.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in
       
       if error != nil {
          print("Error occured in search: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
       } else if response!.mapItems.count == 0 {
          print("No matches found")
       } else {
          print("Matches found")
          
          guard validResponse = response else {return}

          //Instead of looping through all of the items, pick one.
          let item = validResponse.mapItems.randomElement()
             
          print("Name = \(String(describing: item.name))")
          print("Phone = \(String(describing: item.phoneNumber))")
       }
    }
```